# Laravel: api request to filter results

Tags: php, json, laravel

First, I will show you a summary of the content of the results:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "سرویس نرم افزاری",
        "reviewDate": "2023-06-19",
        "description": null,
        "responsibles": [
            {
                "id": 18,
                "assetId": 2,
                "userId": 2,
                "type": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 19,
                "assetId": 2,
                "userId": 4,
                "type": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "reviewDate": "2023-06-19",
        "description": null,
        "responsibles": [
            {
                "id": 22,
                "assetId": 3,
                "userId": 2,
                "type": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 23,
                "assetId": 3,
                "userId": 4,
                "type": 2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The content of the function that performs the filter operation is as follows:

```
    public function AssetsFilter(Request $request){
        $assets = Asset::with('responsibles');
        foreach ($request->all() as $filter) {
            foreach ($filter as $column => $value) {
                $filterType = $value['filterType'];
                $filterValue = $value['filterValue'];

                $relationshipColumn = explode('.', $column);
                if (count($relationshipColumn) === 2) {
                    $relationship = $relationshipColumn[0];
                    $column = $relationshipColumn[1];

                    $assets->whereHas($relationship, function (Builder $query) {
                        $query->where('content', 'like', 'code%');
                    })->get();
                    $assets->whereHas($relationship, function (Builder $query) use ($column, $filterType, $filterValue) {
                        if ($filterType === 'LIKE') {
                            $query->where($column, 'LIKE', '%' . $filterValue . '%');
                        } else {
                            $query->where($column, $filterType, $filterValue);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    if ($filterType === 'LIKE') {
                        $assets->where($column, 'LIKE', '%' . $filterValue . '%');
                    } else {
                        $assets->where($column, $filterType, $filterValue);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $assets->get();
    }
```

The function works perfectly for filtering the results, but it does not work correctly for filtering the part of the results that contains the array. For example, this part of the result:

```
"responsibles": [
            {
                "id": 22,
                "assetId": 3,
                "userId": 2,
                "type": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 23,
                "assetId": 3,
                "userId": 4,
                "type": 2
            }
        ]
```

Sending a filter request in Postman is as follow (as a Post request in Body->raw):

```
[
    {
        "responsibles.userId": {
            "filterType": "!=",
            "filterValue": 4
        }
    }
]
```

As you can see, I have requested that the results be in a form where there is no Responsible.UserID 4. But there is still Responsible.UserID 4 in the results

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't recommend having multiple/nested `loop` conditions to generate a database SQL query. But in this scenario, you can play with the eloquent method: `Model::with()` to [eager loadi](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the data and `Model::whereHas()` to [query the relationship existence](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).

```
public function AssetsFilter(Request $request)
{
    $assets = Asset::query();

    foreach ($request->all() as $filter) {
        foreach ($filter as $column => $value) {
            $filterType = $value['filterType'];
            $filterValue = $value['filterValue'];

            $relationshipColumn = explode('.', $column);
            if (count($relationshipColumn) === 2) {
                $relationship = $relationshipColumn[0];
                $column = $relationshipColumn[1];

                $assets->with([
                    $relationship => function ($query) use ($column, $filterType, $filterValue) {
                        return $query->when(
                            $filterType === 'LIKE',
                            fn ($q) =>  $q->where($column, 'LIKE', '%' . $filterValue . '%'),
                            fn ($q) =>  $q->where($column, $filterType, $filterValue)
                        );
                    }
                ])->whereHas($relationship, function ($query) use ($column, $filterType, $filterValue) {
                    return $query->when(
                        $filterType === 'LIKE',
                        fn ($q) =>  $q->where($column, 'LIKE', '%' . $filterValue . '%'),
                        fn ($q) =>  $q->where($column, $filterType, $filterValue)
                    );
                });

            } else {
                $assets->when(
                    $filterType === 'LIKE',
                    fn ($query) => $query->where($column, 'LIKE', '%' . $filterValue . '%'),
                    fn ($query) => $query->where($column, $filterType, $filterValue)
                );
            }
        }
    }
    return $assets->get();
}
```

Also, you can apply [withWhereHas()](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads-with-relationship-existence) to achieve the same result and clean up the repeated code.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. Just one issue. The results are as if when we say !=, it displays the asset and removes only the part that we didn't want. While it should remove the asset from the list of results

Comment: @AliBabae you mean if the result of the relation is empty then other data of the asset should be shown?

Comment: It's like a search with specific conditions. The search conditions are as follows: LIKE,=,!=

Comment: No, with != condition you just removed that part of responsible array, not the asset array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254267/discussion-between-js-tech-and-ali-babae).

Comment: @miken32 Absolutely you are right! It is important to validate those variables initially for validation before proceeding to subsequent steps. AliBabae, please take note of this as well.